# MSDeploy not working 

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, msdeploy

I'm trying to deploy a .NET 4.0 project with Visual Studio 2010 using MSDeploy; however when I right-click on the project, what shows up is the legacy context menu for Visual Studio 2008 ('Publish Website', 'Build Website' etc.) in lieu of the VS 2010 context menu ('Publish', 'Build' etc.). I'm running Windows Vista and IIS 7.0.

Ideas, anyone?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

It appears this happens when you open a Framework 3.5 solution using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: so it seems although a lot of marketing hype surrounds this new deployment, to me its still the same old crap.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when a website is created as opposed to a web project.